# unset curl CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have an PHP class which is used to POST some data to a server, and GET some data back using the same open connection.
The problem is that this code will try to POST data from 1st request, in the 2nd request...

```
curl_setopt(self::$ecurl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt(self::$ecurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$request=curl_exec(self::$ecurl);
curl_setopt(self::$ecurl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$request=curl_exec(self::$ecurl);
```

So i need the way to unset `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. I tried to use `curl_setopt(self::$ecurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);`, but anyway curl send `Posting 0 bytes...` in request's header.

Also please note, that i need to use exactly the same connection, so I can't create another connection via curl_init.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` to `true` prior to the last request.

From [PHP.net](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

CURLOPT_HTTPGET

*TRUE to reset the HTTP request method to GET. Since GET is the default, this is only necessary if the request method has been changed.*

Comment: quick note - I was trying to remove CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS like this: `curl_setopt($curl CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, false);` but apparently even setting them to false changes the request method back to POST.  So make sure not to set POSTFIELDS to false **after** settings the request type.

Comment: You are right, there are options, which set the request type implicitly. Usually in cases when the typical workload is the one to which the given option sets it.

Answer (score -1):

You could add your curl options into an array and use [curl_setopt_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php)

This will make it easy to unset (or set) your options array elements.

```
$options = array(
               CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.example.com/',
               CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
               CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data
           );

// condition on which you want to unset
if ($condition == true) {
    unset($options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]);
}
...
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);
```

I understand this was an old question but still think this method can be handy.

Comment: That doesn't work for the situation in the original question where they're re-using the Curl object ($ch) which has previously had CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS already set as an option.